# SequenceGenerator not using next value of databasesequence

Tags: oracle, hibernate, sequence

I have a problem in my application. I have an Oracle database with a sequence on a table. When i view the sequence in the database it says that last_number is 33800. However, when I try inserting a new object from my application the generated id is not 33800, but rather a smaller number. My guess is that Hibernate or whatever just finds the next available number. It does happen that my application deletes rows in the table, thus causing holes in the id-sequence. So, eventually I will get an exception because an ID i am trying to insert has already been used.

How can I configure the application so that it is always the sequence's last number + 1 that is used? I thought that this was default behavior, as I cannot recall encountering this problem.

This is my entity:
 
    `@Entity
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "SequenceIdGenerator", sequenceName = "MY_SEQ", allocationSize = 20)
    @Table(name = "myEntity")
    public class myEntity {
        private Long id;
        @Id
        @Column(name = "id")
        @GeneratedValue(generator = "SequenceIdGenerator")
        public Long getId() {
            return id;
        }
        public void setId(final Long id) {
            this.id = id;
        } 
    }`

Comment: An Oracle SEQUENCE as defined in the database will not guarantee that you will get the last highest number +1. They don't work that way and you are likely to get gaps in the sequence. However, it shouldn't go backwards unless it has CYCLEd or been recreated.

Comment: Hmm, so why does it presumably go backwards. I haven't cycled or recreated the sequence, that I know of. The behavior I am experiencing seems a bit weird to me.

Comment: Could you perhaps have the wrong sequence being incremented because of the way Hibernate is configured ? This is one of the disadvantages of an ORM; things are hidden and done behind the scenes which hides the simplicity of a simple database call.

Answer (score 0):

you can let hibernate handle this by

```
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private Long id;
```

you can read more about it here https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Identity_and_Sequencing

You are using ORACLE so for you `GenerationType.SEQUENCE` will work as `GenerationType.IDENTITY` is not supported by Oracle

Comment: I can try, but how does this work with entities already created using the old sequencegenerator?

Comment: you can read more about it here https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Identity_and_Sequencing